# Is it possible to optimize maven dependencies automatically?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I am working on a big project that consists of about 40 sub-projects with very not optimized dependencies. There are declared dependencies that are not in use as well as used but undeclared dependencies. The second case is possible when dependency is added via other dependency.

I want to remove redundant and add required dependencies. I ran `mvn dependency:analyze` and got a long list of warnings I have to fix now.

I wonder whether there is maven plugin or any other utility that can update my `pom.xml` files automatically. I tried to do it manually but it takes a lot of time. It seems it will take a couple of days of copy/paste to complete the task.

In worse case I can write such script myself but probably ready stuff exists?

Here is how `mvn dependency:analyze` reports dependency warnings:

```
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1:compile
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[WARNING]    org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
```

Comment: +1 Totally agree this would be extremely useful. It'd be great if there was some way to automatically organize all dependencies inside a large multi-module project.

Comment: Very unsure if it's even possible to discover all runtime dependencies. In either case, you will need extensive testing of the application when the cleanup is done. I'd probably just go through the dependencies one by one, removing all that could be unused, then re adding them as usage is discovered.

Comment: Are you talking about used but undeclared provided-scope dependencies from dependent projects? For transitive compile dependencies, I'd think you would just want to let Maven pull those in automatically.

Answer (score 7):

I would not say: **with very not optimized dependencies.** it's simply someone has not done his job well, cause defining dependencies which are not used shows someone didn't understand what a build tools is and how its working. That can be compared with a Java file which contains many unused imports. In the case of the unused imports in a Java sources this can simply be handle by the IDE but for dependencies in Maven there does not exist such a simple way as already been expressed the problem are kinds of DI etc. which makes this job hard. You can try to output the result of dependency:analyze into a script (there exist an option for that goal) and afterwards test the resulting build after cleaning up the dependencies.

It might be a good idea to run

```
mvn dependency:analyze -DscriptableOutput=true
```

which produces output which can be very simple extracted from the output and can be used for further processing like using as input for the versions-maven-plugin (with some pre conversion).

Comment: I 100% agree with your conclusions about person that created those pom.xml file. But nothing to do: this is my job now. Thank you for `-DscriptableOutput`. Unfortunately it does not give me too much. It just adds yet another line that contains *missing* dependencies only but does not contain redundant dependencies. Anyway probably I will use this option if I will write my own converter of `dependency:analyze` report to XML fragment that can be copy/pasted to pom.xml

Comment: Ta-da! This will give you XML you can paste into your poms as you see fit. Should save some typing. Snippets are grouped by pom for your convenience. `mvn dependency:analyze -DscriptableOutput=true | grep "\\$\\$%%%" | awk '{split($1,arr,":"); poms[arr[2]]=poms[arr[2]] "<dependency>\n    <groupId>" arr[3] "</groupId>\n    <artifactId>" arr[4] "</artifactId>\n    <version>" arr[6] "</version>\n</dependency>\n"} END {for (pom in poms) {print pom "\n" poms[pom]}}'`

Comment: @MarkCrossfield works in linux only, anything for windows?

Comment: @BennyBottema You should be able to run the above using [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html) versions of `grep` and `awk`. Exercise caution as written by others—there’s no substitute for hand-crafted dependencies so you’ll likely have some rework to do.

Comment: And for windows as batch file:
`
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=:" %%A in (%1) do (
  echo ^<dependency^>
  echo    ^<groupId^>%%~A^</groupId^>
  echo    ^<artifactId^>%%~B^</artifactId^>
  echo    ^<version^>%%~D^</version^>
  echo    ^<scope^>%%~E^</scope^>
  echo ^</dependency^>
)
`
Make sure you've removes [WARNING] in text editor first.

Answer (score 4):

I would not recommend to clean-up dependencies automatically.

1. Adding of all 'Used undeclared...' lead to duplication of most of transitive dependencies that lead to spending of more time to reading and managing them.
2. Removing of all 'Unused declared...' can lead to errors in run-time because they are: called by reflection or specially declared to override version of the same artifact that already used in 3rd party dependencies (changing their compile scope to runtime is preferable, while test scope should be untouched to avoid leak them to production package) or added to declare usage of an optional transitive dependency of some 3rd party library etc.

Comment: I disagree with point 1. "Used undeclared dependencies" means that the dependencies are directly used by the project (not only transitively), so I think adding them inside the POM clearly indicates which dependencies the project directly uses.

Comment: Adding all of them only do the problem more visible, while source of problem is mixing abstraction from different levels. It is better to refactors system by adding thin adapter layers between domain model and tech modules. http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000780.html